# What does this process STAT indicates?

Tags: process, process-management, ps, stat

[image]

If you check the `STAT column` in above image you will see `Ss S S< SN and R+`
What does this indicates ? `Process states`. 
If yes,Then what is the significance of `'Ss S< SN and R+'`?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

These are indeed the process states. Processes states that ps indicates are:

```
D Uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
R Running or runnable (on run queue)
S Interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
T Stopped, either by a job control signal or because it is being traced.
W paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
X dead (should never be seen)
Z Defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent.
```

and the additional characters are:

```
< high-priority (not nice to other users)
N low-priority (nice to other users)
L has pages locked into memory (for real-time and custom IO)
s is a session leader
l is multi-threaded (using CLONE_THREAD, like NPTL pthreads do)
+ is in the foreground process group
```

You could also find this all by looking in the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ps) for `ps`, specifically the `PROCESS STATE CODES` section.